# How to get a random background_image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an helper method to get a random image :

```
  def home_random_image
    image_path = "app/assets/images/home/"
    image_files = Dir.glob("#{image_path}*")
    image_files.sample
  end
```

In my view :

```
style="background-image: url("<%= home_random_image %>");"
```

But in my my html I get a bad url (without slashs) :

```
style="background-image: url("app asset images home img.jpg")
```

Comment: `image_files.sample.split(image_path)[1]` is removing `image_path` then `"#{image_path}#{image}"` puts it back. How about `image_files.sample`?

Comment: You're right, but the url still badly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried by replacing the inner `"` with `'`?

```
style="background-image: url("<%= home_random_image %>");"
```

becomes

```
style="background-image: url('<%= home_random_image %>');"
```